# In a partial SASS file, how can I use a variable defined in the parent?

Tags: sass

In my `main.scss` file, I use the following two partials with @use:

```
@use 'variables' as v;
// @forward 'variables'; // doesn't work
@use 'layout';
```

In `_layout.scss`, I try to use this variable:

```
h1 {
    color: v.$mainHeaderColor;
}
```

But it gives me the error:

> There is no module with the namespace "v".

> color: v.$mainHeaderColor;

How can I load all my partials in my `main.scss` so that every partial can use every other partial, which was possible with @import i.e. before @use namespaces.

Comment: So bizarre that there's radio silence on this. They are telling us @import is deprecated but so little info on how to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

> There is no module with the namespace "v". - color: v.$mainHeaderColor;

Your receiving the error when compiling `main.scss` because the `_layout.scss` partial file doesn't know about the namespace "v" and wasn't able to load the members like `$mainHeaderColor` from the `_variables.scss` module. This happens because `_layout.scss` doesn't have a `@use` rule loading the members from "variables", therefore it can't access variables defined in that module.

A "quick" fix would be to introduce a `@use` rule in your `_layout.scss` file to load the variables from `_variables.scss` like this:

```
@use "./variables" as v;

/* _layout.scss */

h1 {
    color: v.$mainHeaderColor;
}
```

Now there really isn't a need to use `@forward` with your current structure as its only two partial files being loaded into `main.scss`. If you want to use `@forward` I'd recommend reading further and setting up directories with index files.

To update your main file, this is how loading the files with `@use` at-rules into `main.scss` would look:

```
@use 'variables' as v;
@use 'layout';

/* main.scss */

/* Use the loaded members from '_variables.scss' inside the main file */
.demo {
  color: v.$mainHeadColor;
}
```

### Using @use rules along with @forward and index files

With the [`@import`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) at-rule slowly being phased out of the main implementation of [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation), (dart-sass). It's time for us to adopt [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) rules and learn how to utilize the cool features like [index files](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#index-files) with  [`@forward`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward) and setting custom namespaces for loaded modules.

Since `@import` at-rules made everything globally accessible, this is where I've seen most of the confusion around usage of `@use` come into play. We have to make sure all files have appropriate knowledge of variables, mixins, functions etc if they aren't defined in the same partial or file.

---

If you have a `main.scss` Sass file that is going to be compiled with two (or more) imported partial files. The best way to utilize `@use` and `@forward` rules is by creating a directory at the same level as your `main.scss` file (or elsewhere just use the correct path) and create an index file, `_index.scss` to load the entire directory of partials with a single @use rule.

> Note: All `@use` at-rules must be placed at the top of the file.

This index file will be where you place your `@forward` rules, using `@forward "<url>";` for each partial you want to load into the index file. Think of it as one big module that you can load elsewhere with a single `@use` rule in your `main.scss` file, thus giving you access to all of the partial files loaded into that index file within the `/partials` directory.

```
- main.scss 
- partials/
  - _index.scss
  - _variables.scss
  - _layout.scss
  ...
```

Going along with the example, lets say your `_variables.scss` partial file looked like this and wasn't relying on any other files:

```
$mainHeaderColor: #222;
$someOtherVar: #f06;
```

and if the `_layout.scss` partial wanted to use variables defined in `_variables.scss`, we would have to include a `@use` rule to let `_layout.scss` "know" about the loaded members.

```
@use "./variables" as v;

/* _layout.scss */

h1 {
    /* now this works as expected */
    color: v.$mainHeaderColor;
}
```

If you didn't want to define a namespace when loading with @use, simply write `@use "<url>" as <namespace>;` where the namespace being an asterisk `*` signals that a namespace won't be defined so you can use it like `color: $mainHeaderColor` instead of `v.$mainHeaderColor`. Note, this can leading to naming conflicts if your not careful.

Now to load these partials into the `main.scss` file which will be compiled, you could either use two separate `@use` rules for the `_layout.scss` and `_variables.scss` partials or create an index file (`_index.scss`) and load the `/partials` directory with a single `@use` at-rule giving you access to all the partials in the directory.

```
@forward "./variables";
@forward "./layout";

/* partials/_index.scss */
```

Voila! Now all that is left is to load the `/partials` directory into the `main.scss` file to be compiled and maybe used later on. The `_layout.scss` partial is loaded into `main.scss` through our single `@use` rule and we also have access to `_variables.scss` variables or any other partial file that was forwarded in the index file.

```
@use "./partials" as *;

/* main.scss */

h2 {
  color: $mainHeaderColor;
  background: $someOtherVar;
}
```

If you had a directory of mixins like `./mixins`, then you would follow the same workflow of placing all partial files inside the `/mixins` directory and then create an `_index.scss` file to load the partials with `@forward` rules. To finally load the directory with a single `@use` rule giving you access to all of the partials loaded in a specific directory through an index file. I used the `/partials` directory as a "starting" point but it would make more sense to create a directory `/vars`, `/mixins` etc and place files in their respective directories for better structure/organization.

Answer (score 1):

... and still no one has answered what the man asked.

I find it unbelievable that I've been trying for hours to find a solution to do this without using "@import".

The problem is so simple and yet no one simply answers with a straight solution. If we use an above example, he wants to have the variable `$mainHeaderColor` defined in the `main.scss` file, not in the `_variables.scss` partial. How then to `@use` the parent file since this would include all CSS from all child files?

I think the people who were "improving" SCSS seriously messed something up, as I am going back to `@import` as probably 99% of people.

Has anybody have simple solution?

Comment: While `@import` would fix this issue, please note `@import` is deprecated, and the sass team is planning to phase it out over the next few years, [according to their docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/).