# importing outside style to scss main page

Tags: sass, partials

I have a main.scss file that I want to import colors into from a _colors file.
I have defined a body color in the color file, when I try to import it, I see no changes in the webpage. They are both in the same scss folder but neither @include or @import seem to make a difference. I have tried with and without the underscore in my import statement, both single and double quotes and both import and include keywords. Please tell me what stupid mistake I am making that will rectify this problem as I have researched the problem and think I have been able to copy the examples with no success.

```
 _colors.scss

body {
  $background-color: maroon;
}

    main.scss

@include 'colors';
```

Answer (score 0):

Partials are used with `@use` directive. Then,

```
_colours.scss

body{
    background-color: maroon;
}

style.scss

@use "_colours";
```

The reuse of code is done through the `@mixin` directive.

```
_colours.scss

@mixin body--background{
    background-color:maroon;
}

style.scss

@use "_colours.scss" as so;

body{
    @include so.body--background;
}
```

But, if you want to just define just colours use variables instead. Example below,

```
_colours.scss

$maroon=maroon;
$lightblue=//et cetera.

style.scss

@use "_colours";

body{
   background-color:$maroon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `main.scss` file which will be the file that gets compiled, and you want to import variables, mixins etc from another partial file, such as `_colors.scss`. You could do so by loading the members from the partial `_colors.scss` into `main.scss` with a [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) at-rule. This allows loaded members from the module to be referenced with dot-notation throughout your `main.scss` stylesheet.

Let's say your `_colors.scss` file looked like this:

```
$bodyColor: maroon;
$someOtherColor: #f06;

/* adding a mixin for demo */
@mixin highlight($c, $bg) {
  color: $c;
  background: $bg;
}

/* some extra styles pertaining to _color.scss */
.some-styles { 
  color: $someOtherColor; 
}
```

> Note: The syntax for `@use` is `@use <url> as <namespace>;`.

You could load the variables/mixins etc into `main.scss` with a `@use` rule and reference the namespace throughout your program:

```
@use "./colors" as c;

body {
 background-color: c.$bodyColor;
}

.highlighted {
  @include c.highlight(#fff, #f06); 
}
```

or without defining a namespace like:

```
@use "./colors" as *;

body {
 background-color: $bodyColor;
}

.highlighted {
  @include highlight(#fff, #f06); 
}
```

You certainly can include a `body {}` declaration inside `_colors.scss` and load it the same way as discussed above, but I think your wanting to place the `body` style block inside `main.scss` and simply reference loaded variables from `_color.scss`. If you have a directory of many partials and want to load them into `main.scss` without writing separate `@use` rules for each load, then introduce a [index file](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#index-files) with `@forward` rules to load an entiry directory of partials into `main.scss` using a single `@use` rule.

Comment: See [how can I use a variable defined in the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602149/in-a-partial-sass-file-how-can-i-use-a-variable-defined-in-the-parent/68880119#68880119) for a more in-depth explanation on using index files and `@forward` along with `@use`.